# Install Zotac NVIDIA Linux x86_64 drivers in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation

Had to pull ideas from several sources to get this to work, so I thought I'd outline the steps here in one post.

I just bought a Zotac GEForce GT630 video card (model ZT-60416-20L).  I went with Zotac because they're not shy about announcing their Linux support.  You can download Linux drivers right from their website (http://www.zotac.com/support/download.html). Downloaded the x64 driver.

Got an error that "You appear to be running an X server", also various errors about Nouveau drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to finish the installation:

Hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to a TTY.
Login as yourself (or whatever user).
Run `sudo init 3`

Now kill the lightdm service:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

Check it with:

```
sudo service lightdm status
```

Start installing the driver:

```
cd ~/Downloads
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-343.13.run ## or the appropriate version of the driver
sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-343.13.run
```

Follow the prompts to uninstall Nouveau driver when it complains!

You will have to reboot, then restart this process from the top. Eventually you will get through the whole installation without any errors except the `pre-install script has failed` error, which is harmless.